# Switching to Vertica from MySql, aggregate in where clause not working

Tags: sql, vertica

Recently we have switched to Vertica from MySQL. I am lost on how to re-create the <=30 check inside the where clause in the query below. This currently does not work in Vertica, but does in MySQL.

Essentially, a user owns cars and cars have parts. I want to total the amount of cars and car parts in a timeframe, but only for users who have less than or equal to 30 cars.

```
select
    count(distinct cr.id) as 'Cars',
    count(distinct cp.id) as 'Car Parts'
from
    users u
inner join
    user_emails ue on u.id = ue.user_id
inner join
    cars cr on cr.user_id = u.id
inner join
    car_parts cp on cp.car_id = cr.id
where
    (
        select count(*) from cars where cars.user_id=u.id
    ) <=30
and
    ue.is_real = true and ue.is_main = true
and
    cr.created_at >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00' and cr.created_at <= '2017-02-17 23:59:59'
```

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated!

Before my mouse flies away and my monitors goes blank, I get this error:

> ERROR: Correlated subquery with aggregate function COUNT is not supported

Comment: This doesn't work in Vertica?

Comment: In what way does it "not work"? Mouse flies away? monitor turns off?Gives you indigestion?

Comment: Ha ha. Apologies on the lack of info - I get the following error: "ERROR: Correlated subquery with aggregate function COUNT is not supported"

Comment: Please update the question with this information next time instead of raising a new comment, sure add the comment to say "Thanks @Nick.McDermaid " but keep the important stuff in the question

Comment: I'll add the error for you

Comment: Thanks @ChrisSchaller and @Nick.McDermaid!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a subquery this way.  You would use a window function:

```
select count(distinct cr.id) as Cars,
       count(distinct cp.id) as CarParts
from users u join
     user_emails ue
     on u.id = ue.user_id join
     (select cr.*, count(*) over (partition by user_id) as cnt
      from cars cr
     ) cr
     on cr.user_id = u.id join
     car_parts cp
     on cp.car_id = cr.id
where cr.cnt <= 30 and
      ue.is_real = true and ue.is_main = true
      cr.created_at >= '2017-01-01' and
      cr.created_at < '2017-02-18';
```

Notes:

- Don't enclose column aliases in single quotes.  That is a bug waiting to happen.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.
- You can simplify the date logic.  Using `<` is better than `<=` to capture everything that happens on a particular day.

Comment: This works great! I see that partition did the trick... I need to read up some more on this to fully understand it. This set me on the right path - I really appreciate it! And your tips are duly noted